# How to know whether it is File or a Directory in GWT?

Tags: gwt

How would I know that it is file or a directory , cause I have to check a condition that if it is a file then return a particular image for the files and if it is directory then return different image for that,

`isDirectory()` and `isFile()` method are not working in GWT. 
Kindly give the solution for GWT.

Comment: Is this on the client? If so, what's the use-case? If it's on the server, then the methods you listed will work just fine.

Comment: Yes , it is on the client side. and I need to validate on client side itself. Kindly suggest something

Comment: Is it a file that's coming from the server or from the client?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [GWT Elemental](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/elemental.html). It brings a HTML5 File API (besides WebGL, WebAudio, Shadow DOM,...), with which you should check if it is a directory or file (on client-side):

```
FileEntry fileEntry = (FileEntry)entry;
fileEntry.isDirectory();
fileEntry.isFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing such operations on the server side. You can always create a bean with the required properties which can be used on the client side.